Sending documents from Python to Telegram bot issue
I have an issue I would like your help with. I am working on a file monitor script to send hit files to a Telegram bot. The files in my system are named like this.
lordofthepings.xyz_8080_️️️_Q‌n‌t‌m‌F‌s‌p‌

But when I send them from Python, they come through like this:
lordofthepings.xyz_8080_    _QntmFsp
(Notice the special characters missing)

I have been going round and round with encoding. I have also been doing the rounds with all the AI I can find to see if they can fix the issue, but with no luck. It's not really; a problem, it's just annoying, as the script works great apart from this one little thing. Maybe it's just the way it is, and I will have to remove these types of characters.
This is the part of the code where I think the problem lies.
def send_document(file_path, filename):

        try:

            if is_windows:

                with open(file_path, 'rb') as document:

                    bot.send_document(chat_id, document, caption=filename)

            else:

                url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendDocument"

                with open(file_path, 'rb') as document:

                    files = {'document': document}

                    data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'caption': filename}

                    response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)

                    if response.status_code != 200:

                        raise Exception(f"Error: {response.text}")

            print(f"Sent {filename} successfully!")

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"Error sending {filename}: {e}")


Try encoding the filename with urllib.parse.quote
